# Satoshi Nakamoto Renaissance Holdings' website is Wordpress? Is it safe?

Tags: wordpress, websites

So, Satoshi Nakamoto, creator of Bitcoin has announced that he will supposedly be revealing his real identity. I find the fact that Satoshi's company website is hosted on Wordpress to be endlessly amusing for some reason. I mean, I get it, I use wordpress myself but I always saw it as endlessly vulnerable from a security perspective and I don't trust anything of true value to it. Satoshi, being a brilliant crypto expert and developer (I'm assuming) using Wordpress confuses me.

https://satoshinrh.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsatoshinrh.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Should Satoshi expect problems with his site? Could this be an indicator that this site is not genuine? The SSL certificate was recently issued so it's possible this is a placeholder website? It's only domain validation so I suppose it doesn't guarantee anything other than integrity of connection with the server...

Anyway, I'm simply very amused and would like to know if anyone finds that this is a dangerous decision on Satoshi's part. I'm by no means a security expert but Wordpress for anything other than a blog gives me the heeby-jeebies.

Comment: Just because it is Wordpress does not make it a security risk. WP security problems stem from the plugins, not the framework.

Comment: "Could this be an indicator that this site is not genuine?"  A better question would be:  Is there any reason to believe the site might *BE* genuine?  And the answer to that question, in my opinion, is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way anyone would be able to prove they created the network is by moving Bitcoins out of one of the very first (and oldest) blocks (EDIT: or signing something with their private key). As this is not demonstrated on the website, the fact of whether it is secure, hosted on WordPress or any other indication is irrelevant.

I think it's safe to say that this website is not genuine.

Comment: He could also sign a message with his private key.

Comment: Yep, that works as well. But I were them, I'd send a transaction as it's arguably easier to verify and thus might attract more press